# Beautiful Soup find first <a> whose title attribute equal a certain string

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with beautiful soup and am trying to grab the first  tag on a page that has the attribute equal to a certain string.

For example:

```
<a href="url" title="export"></a>
```

What I've been trying to do is grab the href of the first  that is found whose title is "export".

- If I use `soup.select("a[title='export']")` then I end up finding all tags who satisfy this requirement, not just the first.
- If I use `find("a", {"title":"export"})` with conditions being set such that the title should equal "export", then it grabs the actual items inside the  tag, not the href.
- If I write `.get("href")` after calling `find()`, I get None back.

I've been searching the documentation and stack overflow for an answer but have yet found one. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want? The href or the content?

Comment: I stated in my question: I want the href of the first <a> that is found whose title is "export"

Comment: Okay... `soup.find('a', {title : 'export' })['href']` should do it.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work for some. Though, I'm getting an error about halfway that 'Nonetype' is not subscriptable. I'll look into it. I think the website blocked my IP halfway because of the scrape. But the question here is solved

Comment: Okay, have addressed that issue in an answer I wrote. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What I've been trying to do is grab the href of the first that is found whose title is "export".

You're almost there. All you need to do is, once you've obtained the tag, you'll need to just index it to get the href. Here's a slightly more bulletproof version:

```
try:
    url = soup.find('a', {'title' : 'export'})['href']  
    print(url)
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

following the same topic in the html file I would like to find just the patent number, title of the citations from the HTML tag. I tried this but it prints all the titles in the HTML file, but I specifically want it under the citations only.

````
url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1208209A1/en?oq=medicinal+chemistry'
patent = html_file.read() 
#print(patent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(patent, 'html.parser')
x=soup.select('tr[itemprop="backwardReferences"]')
 y=soup.select('td[itemprop="title"]')
print(y)```
````